# Can anyone help me solve this? I can't see a pattern anywhere

Tags: pattern

[image: Colored Squares]

I would appreciate any help that I can get on solving this riddle. I've been staring at this for hours and no patterns are occurring to me.

Comment: is there any background, a source, a hint, anything?

Comment: Is `A` correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

I find following as an answer:

> C

Explanation:

Counting purple squares for all blocks(3 x 3)

> for first row only: 3 2 1

Counting purple squares for all blocks(3 x 3)

> for first column only: 2 2 2

Counting purple squares for all blocks(3 x 3)

> for last row: 3 2 -

Counting purple squares for all blocks(3 x 3)

> for last column: 2 2 -

Out of the 6 options,

> C is the only option containing 1 purple square in last row (thus to make 3 2 1 combination for last row blocks) and 2 purple squares in last column (thus to make 2 2 2 combination for last column blocks)

Answer (score 0):

So, in trying to look for patterns, I noticed the white squares within each block of 9.

I see:

0 2 2

1 3 3

2 1 ?

I'm not sure here. My gut says go with a box that has a single white square to complete it. But that doesn't exist... So I go with (A).

(A) = 4 white squares.

0 2 2

1 3 3

2 1 4

Reading each column from top to bottom, left to right:

0 1 2;  2 3 1;  2 3 4.

I'm seeing some kind of pattern in the numbers, but not sure what to call it.

Answer (score 0):

> I think it is C.

"Reason": Take only the **bottom left** and the **bottom middle** field of each 3x3 square.
Now search for it in the big field

For A: White + Purple -> it's also on the bottom middle 3x3 field

For B: White + Blue -> it's also top middle

For C: Red + White -> doesn't exist

For D: Blue + White -> middle, left

For E: Red + Blue -> middle, middle

For F: Purple + Red -> middle, right